# Unable to add a class to the DBContext class while creating a controller with views and entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning Asp.Net MVC and I have written a class:

I'm trying to add a controller with read,write actions and views using Entity Framework. But, when I'm giving MovieDBContext as the DB Context class, it is throwing an error while scaffolding that, MovieDBContext was not found.

Do I have to add some packages or something?

Why is the class not being detected as the DB Context class

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MVCMovieApplication.Models
{
    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the exact error message you get? You can [edit] your question to add that.